# conversion failed when converting date /time from character string

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

[image]

```
SELECT [PROC_ID]
    ,[CONTACT_DATE_new]
    ,[CPT_CODE_new]
    ,[CHARGEABLE_YN_new]
    ,cat.CDM_Category
    ,DateUpdated
FROM
    [dbo].CDM_Audit_EAP_OT]
WHERE 
    @ColDate BETWEEN @Start_Date AND @End_Date
```

After I add a new parameter `@ColDate`, I start getting the above error.

`@ColDate` has "CONTACT_DATE_new" or "DateUpdated". Users will choose either one depend on what they are looking for.

If I just specify the column directly, the report will work fine.

```
 WHERE CONTACT_DATE_new BETWEEN @Start_Date AND @End_Date
 WHERE DateUpdated BETWEEN @Start_Date AND @End_Date
```

Comment: `@coldate`- is this an actual column?

Comment: You know that your first query will be equivalent to something like `WHERE 'DateUpdated' BETWEEN '2014-07-21' AND '2015-07-21'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@ColDate` in your query is not treated as a column name, instead as a string type variable. When you try to compare its values with `@startdate` and `@enddate` it fails. Hence the error. You can create a stored procedure as follows to suit your need :-

```
Create PROCEDURE [SSRSReport]

@Start_Date date,
@End_Date date,
@ColDate nvarchar(25)

AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

declare @sql1 nvarchar(max)

if @ColDate = 'CONTACT_DATE_new'

begin
set @sql1 = 
'SELECT [PROC_ID]
    ,[CONTACT_DATE_new]
    ,[CPT_CODE_new]
    ,[CHARGEABLE_YN_new]
    ,cat.CDM_Category
    ,DateUpdated
FROM
    [dbo].CDM_Audit_EAP_OT]
WHERE 
    CONTACT_DATE_new BETWEEN ''' + cast(Convert(nvarchar(10),@Start_Date ,120) as Nvarchar(max)) +''' 
    AND ''' + cast(Convert(nvarchar(10),@End_Date ,120) as Nvarchar(max)) + ''''
    end

    else if @ColDate = 'DateUpdated'

    begin
set @sql1 = 
'SELECT [PROC_ID]
    ,[CONTACT_DATE_new]
    ,[CPT_CODE_new]
    ,[CHARGEABLE_YN_new]
    ,cat.CDM_Category
    ,DateUpdated
FROM
    [dbo].CDM_Audit_EAP_OT]
WHERE 
    DateUpdated BETWEEN ''' + cast(Convert(nvarchar(10),@Start_Date ,120) as Nvarchar(max)) +''' 
    AND ''' + cast(Convert(nvarchar(10),@End_Date ,120) as Nvarchar(max)) + ''''
    end

    print @sql1
    exec sp_executesql @sql1

end
```

Answer (score 1):

please use the belowstatement in where clause. I did not test below scripts.

```
SELECT [PROC_ID]
        ,[CONTACT_DATE_new]
        ,[CPT_CODE_new]
        ,[CHARGEABLE_YN_new]
        ,cat.CDM_Category
        ,DateUpdated
    FROM
        [dbo].[CDM_Audit_EAP_OT]
where
   (@locationType = 'DateUpdated' AND (DateUpdated BETWEEN @Start_Date AND @End_Date)
```

**CASE**

```
SELECT [PROC_ID]
        ,[CONTACT_DATE_new]
        ,[CPT_CODE_new]
        ,[CHARGEABLE_YN_new]
        ,cat.CDM_Category
        ,DateUpdated
    FROM
        [dbo].[CDM_Audit_EAP_OT]
    where    
    CASE 
    when @locationType =  'DateUpdated' and (DateUpdated BETWEEN @Start_Date AND @End_Date) then 1
    Else 0
    End = 1
```

Comment: Your CASE expression won't work. A CASE expression is not for control of flow; it returns a single value.